# Invalid date of birth while using OSI sabre

Tags: soap, sabre

I have a sabre to sabre api request in which I need to create the passenger name record without using the passport information . But when I do the request it gives the following error

```
<TYPE>BusinessLogic</TYPE><TIMESTAMP>2018-06-04T11:32:33.948-05:00</TIMESTAMP><SYSTEMSPECIFICRESULTS><MESSAGE><content>INVALID DATE OF BIRTH - USE DDMMMYY</content><CODE>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</CODE></MESSAGE></SYSTEMSPECIFICRESULTS>
```

The date of birth format works fine when I use the passport information while creating the passenger name record . Below is my request sample .

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" version="3.3.0" IgnoreOnError="true" HaltOnError="true">
    <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="true" RedisplayReservation="true">
        <EndTransactionRQ>
            <EndTransaction Ind="true"/>
            <Source ReceivedFrom="Lorem ipsum"/>
        </EndTransactionRQ>
    </PostProcessing>
    <PriceQuoteInfo xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
        <Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="2"/>
        <Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="3"/>
    </PriceQuoteInfo>
    <SpecialReqDetails xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <AddRemarkRQ>
            <RemarkInfo>
                <FOP_Remark Type="CASH"/>
            </RemarkInfo>
        </AddRemarkRQ>
        <SpecialServiceRQ>
            <SpecialServiceInfo>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="1996-02-23" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                        <GivenName>Edna</GivenName>
                        <Surname>Lindsey</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </SecureFlight>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="2015-08-14" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1">
                        <GivenName>Ada</GivenName>
                        <Surname>Hughes</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </SecureFlight>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="2017-04-11" Gender="M" NameNumber="3.1">
                        <GivenName>Lena</GivenName>
                        <Surname>Pope</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </SecureFlight>
                <Service SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="CHLD">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="2.1"/>
                    <Text>Hughes/Ada/14AUG15</Text>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </Service>
                <Service SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="INFT">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
                    <Text>Pope/Lena/11APR17</Text>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </Service>
                <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
                    <Text>ID CARD Number 223341</Text>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </Service>
                <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="2.1"/>
                    <Text>ID CARD Number 2211</Text>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </Service>
                <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="3.1"/>
                    <Text>ID CARD Number 223343</Text>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </Service>
            </SpecialServiceInfo>
        </SpecialServiceRQ>
    </SpecialReqDetails>
    <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <AgencyInfo>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine>HIMAL REISEN</AddressLine>
                <CityName>Kathmandu</CityName>
                <CountryCode>NP</CountryCode>
                <PostalCode>00977</PostalCode>
                <StreetNmbr>12</StreetNmbr>
                <VendorPrefs>
                    <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                </VendorPrefs>
            </Address>
            <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW"/>
        </AgencyInfo>
        <CustomerInfo>
            <ContactNumbers>
                <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="4118125712" PhoneUseType="H"/>
            </ContactNumbers>
            <Email Address="zowo@host.test" NameNumber="1.1"/>
            <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" Infant="false" PassengerType="ADT">
                <GivenName>Edna</GivenName>
                <Surname>Lindsey</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" Infant="false" PassengerType="CNN" NameReference="C02">
                <GivenName>Ada</GivenName>
                <Surname>Hughes</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" Infant="true" PassengerType="INF" NameReference="I13">
                <GivenName>Lena</GivenName>
                <Surname>Pope</Surname>
            </PersonName>
        </CustomerInfo>
    </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Some airlines need to passport number (for DOCS) for some routes (for example, you have to send you passport number if you want to fly to USA from Turkey with Delta Airlines), before creating pnr. 
So that you cannot create a pnr without passport number. Which airline are you ticketing? Also can you please try yy-MM-dd date format for SecureFlight birth dates?

Comment: I am trying from kathmandu to delhi

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 other issues with the request other than the one you've got, all in the *SpecialServiceInfo* element.

1.The one that you got, INVALID DATE OF BIRTH - USE DDMMMYY, is because the *Text* element contains information that is not expected for SSR_Code="CHLD". It should only contain the date of birth and not the name, so *14AUG15* instead of *Hughes/Ada/14AUG15*.

```
<Service SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="CHLD">
    <PersonName NameNumber="2.1"/>
    <Text>Hughes/Ada/14AUG15</Text>
    <VendorPrefs>
        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
    </VendorPrefs>
</Service>
```

2.Both the *SSR_Code="OSI"* and *SecureFlight* cannot be assigned to the infant *NameNumber="3.1"*, they should be assigned to the adult *NameNumber="1.1"*. This would return something like: CANNOT ASSOC TO INFANT NAME

```
<Service SSR_Code="OSI">
    <PersonName NameNumber="3.1"/>
    <Text>ID CARD Number 223343</Text>
    <VendorPrefs>
        <Airline Hosted="false"/>
    </VendorPrefs>
</Service>
```

3.For infants, the geneder should be MI and FI, instead of M and F.

```
<SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
    <PersonName DateOfBirth="2017-04-11" Gender="M" NameNumber="3.1">
        <GivenName>Lena</GivenName>
        <Surname>Pope</Surname>
    </PersonName>
</SecureFlight>
```

> You may check format finder for more info:

- **Child SSR:**

  - https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/PassengerNameRecordPNR/PassengerNameRecordFields/SSRandOSIFieldsinPNR/SendanSSR.aspx?ItemID=316450AF736A45EC84616AE0D7A7B43B
- **Secure Flight Formats > Format Definitions:**

  - https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/PassengerNameRecordPNR/TSAPassengerDocumentationSecureFlightAPISPCTC/SecureFlightTransportationSafetyAdministrationTSADocumentation.aspx?ItemID=d6e613fe6d5c4255beb7c70bd56fb4fe